# MySQLi Prepared Statement not working in WHILE Loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a query inside a While loop. However, the Second run is not working. (The While is ended later, after some results get echoed). I've tried calling the second query `$stma`, however this resulted in the same error.

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in PATH on line 96
```

**Code**

```
 // Prepare Query
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, fullname, shortname FROM languages WHERE (state = '0')");
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get result from query.
    $stmt->bind_result($lang_id, $lang_name, $lang_short);
    
    // While Loop
    while($language = $stmt->fetch()){

        // Get Language Texts
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, article_id, article_language, article_text, article_recuse, article_spec FROM article_content WHERE article_id = ? AND article_language = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("is", $artikel_nummer, $lang_short); // This is line 96.
        $stmt->execute();

        // Get result from query.
        $stmt->bind_result($t_id, $t_articleid, $t_language, $t_text, $t_recuse, $t_spec);
        $stmt->fetch();
```

I'm fairly new to prepared statements, so I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. I've ran a `var_dump()` on the query and it returned false, however, running the query elsewhere or outside the WHILE loop is working (When I Define the two variables by hand).

I've echoed `$artikel_nummer` and `$lang_short`, and it returns their values.

The question is the following: Why is the second query not running, and thus returning the error as stated above?

Comment: you're not doing anything with `$language` for the loop, nor for `$lang_id` or `$lang_name`.

Comment: You're overwriting your `$stmt` variable whilst still trying to fetch from it in each iteration

Comment: You're executing the statement before binding the values to it.

Comment: @Phil I meant on line 3

Comment: @Mike that is the correct way to use `bind_result`

Comment: ok, I'm out; see the answer below.

Comment: @Phil mysqli is not my forte.

Comment: You definitely: 1. should be using a JOIN to fetch the records with a single query 2. should not be calling `prepare` inside of a loop (because that ignores the essence of a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you are overriding your `$stm` variable which holds a reference to your initial prepared statement (and indeed is the condition of your loop). For all queries happening inside loop, you must choose a different variable name:

```
while($language = $stmt->fetch()){

        // Get Language Texts
        $_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, article_id, article_language, article_text, article_recuse, article_spec FROM article_content WHERE article_id = ? AND article_language = ?");

        $_stmt->bind_param("is", $artikel_nummer, $lang_short); // This is line 96.
        $_stmt->execute();

        // Get result from query.
        $_stmt->bind_result($t_id, $t_articleid, $t_language, $t_text, $t_recuse, $t_spec);
        $_stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: and `$language` is used where?

Comment: Technically, is it important? I'm concerned with error which is posted in the question.

Comment: Hi there. This seems to resolve the error partially. It runs the loop once now, and after that it displays the same error again.

Comment: @Anquaser please update the question with new information. Add new changes under the heading "Update"

Comment: After another look I found the issue. I'm now first creating a result, `$textresult = $get_text->get_result();` and then fetch it, `$text = $textresult->fetch_assoc();`. This fixed the whole issue. Thank you for your answer.